# Add line-height in paragraph by removing space from top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add the line-height in the paragraph using css. below is my html

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, oratio doctus his an. Nisl saperet delenit ad
       eos, his eros solet vituperata et, has tantas nemore consetetur ne. Nam cu autem nostr overterem. 
       Ne etiam detraxit adversarium eam, rebum epicurei ea ius. Appareat lucilius
       invenire duo eu, an enim oportere duo, vidisse quaerendum at duo.
    </p>
</div>
```

and here is my simple css

```
p {
  line-height: 5.5em;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

it adds proper line height, but I wanted to remove the space from top and bottom marked pink in this below image.

[image]

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I came across the same issue, so I would suggest in the future to use: transform: translateY(-0.6em); <-but change the value accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approximate this using some negative margin but you have to adjust them if you change the line height:

```css
p {
  line-height: 5.5em;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
div {
  overflow:hidden;
}
p::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  margin-top:-3em;
}

p::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:-3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, oratio doctus his an. Nisl saperet delenit ad eos, his eros solet vituperata et, has tantas nemore consetetur ne. Nam cu autem nostr overterem. Ne etiam detraxit adversarium eam, rebum epicurei ea ius. Appareat lucilius invenire
    duo eu, an enim oportere duo, vidisse quaerendum at duo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome... you are genius!