# CSS line height does not go all the way up or down

Tags: css, line-height

I have a problem that I've had for years.

A text with `line-height: 1` will be compact and will reach the top and bottom of the surrounding elements.

A text with another line-height will be more readable but at the same time, it will no longer reach the top and bottom of the surrounding elements.

Here is a code example of the problem and a hackish solution. Changing the line-height or the font size will break it.

Is the a solid fix for this?

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  width: 1rem;
}

.second,
.second2{
  line-height: 2;
}

.second2 {
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}
```

```html
<strong>Problem:</strong> The letter "A" does not align with the red top.<br><br>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">A text that<br>spans on multiple rows</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<strong>Hackish fix:</strong> The letter "A" does align with the red top.<br><br>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second2">A text that<br>spans on multiple rows</div>
</div>
```

*The line-height is taken to the extreme, just to show the effect.*

Comment: I doubt there is a solid fix (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303653/8620333 ). As a side note, this is by design so why you want to fix something that is meant to work that way?

Comment: @TemaniAfif How else would you make a text align with the top of a box if you still want line-height?

Comment: the solution I am linking above. I don't see more robust. In all the cases you need to have a extra property to rectify that gap. You can probably optimize it by introducing calc() to make it more generic.

Comment: I think that [`text-edge: text`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-inline-3/#text-edges) will one day support a better solution, but for now the hacky solution's all that's available.

Comment: @Alohci Great news! It means that I'm not crazy after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've observed, if you give an element containing text:

- a `font-size` of `1em`
- a `line-height` of `2em`

the text will be rendered in the vertical middle of the `line-height`.

The text will still be `1em` tall, but it will now have `0.5em` of space above it and below it.

To (seemingly, though not actually) counteract this vertical-middle-alignment, one approach would be to apply a

```
transform: translateY(-0.5em)
```

to the text-containing element.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.wrap-1,
.wrap-2,
.wrap-3 {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  width: 1rem;
}

.wrap-1 .second {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.wrap-2 .second {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.wrap-3 .second {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.wrap-3 .second p {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translateY(-0.5em);
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-1">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"><p>A text that<br>spans on multiple rows</p></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-2">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"><p>A text that<br>spans on multiple rows</p></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-3">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"><p>A text that<br>spans on multiple rows</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are more than half way there. I don't use `em` but just a number. I've now read that the number 2 in this case is font-size multiply by 2 so it would 2 * 1rem in case the font-size is 1rem. My guess is that a calc function would make it all the way.

Comment: `calc()` sounds like a good idea. You can probably do even more if you combine `calc()` with a [CSS Custom Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) or two.

Comment: Yes, custom property for the font-size to prevent duplication.